# backbone.js - rendering view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

My ListClass looks like this:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },  

    events: {
        'click ul#perpage span': 'setperpage'
    },

    setperpage: function(event) {
        this.collection.perpageurl = '/perpage/' + $(event.target).text();
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {

    template = _.template('\
    <table>\
    <% _(collection).each(function(model){%>\
    <tr><td><%=model.id%></td><td><%=model.name%></td><td><%=model.email%></td></tr>\
    <%}); %>\
    </table>\
    <ul id="perpage">\
    <li><span>5</span></li>\
    <li><span>10</span></li>\
    </ul>\
    ');

        var context = {collection: this.collection.toJSON()};
        $(this.el).html(template(context));
        $('#app').html(this.el);
        return this;
    }
});
```

For some reason, when I first visit the page that loads this view, 5 items show up (which is supposed to happen). But when I hit the "setperpage" event by clicking the `<span>10</span>`, even though the url is updated and then `fetch()` is called, the list never updates. (I've watched the requests w/ firebug, so I know I'm getting back 10 items in json). Why don't they re render? I still only see 5 items.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `this.collection.fetch();` is asynchronous so the call to render will still be using the old data.

You need to wait for the fetch() to complete before calling the render function.

In your initialize function, bind to the render function to the "reset" event.

```
this.collection.on("reset", function() { this.render(); }, this);
```

When you need new data, call

```
this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
```

Comment: While your premise is correct, your solution is wrong. If you bind `this.render` like that, when `this.render` is invoked, the `this` will refer to the wrong thing. You'd have to assign `self = this` then do `self.render` instead.

Comment: FWIW, Also could have been solved by using `this.collection.bind("refresh", (function(self) { return function() {self.render();}; }(this));`. Your solution is probably much clearer though.

Comment: FYI this functionality was renamed to "reset" as of v 0.5.  I'm updating the solution above accordingly.

Comment: To keep the reference to `this` I would use the `_.bind`, or even better, use the Backbone's `Event.on`, third argument is an optional context:
`this.collection.on("reset", function() { this.render(); }, this);`

Comment: why not write it like this? `this.collection.on( 'reset', this.render, this );` ?

Comment: Rather make use of '_.bindAll' in your initialize method than rely on 'self' or 'that' references. Also bare in mind that as of 1.0 you need to pass in 'reset:true' to your fetch call or this won't work.